# $trace{B^TA^{-1}B}$ is a convex function in A and B

Tags: matrices

This is one of our midterm questions. Prove $trace{B^TA^{-1}B}$ is a convex function in A and B. Where A is positive definite matrix of $R^{n\times n}$ and B is a general matrix of $R^{n\times m}$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Thanks for being honest about the fact that this is a midterm question. You are extremely unlikely to get help, however, not just because many of us are educators, but because this is a math question, not a *Mathematica* question.

Comment: The exam has been graded. The answer is not given.